# How to sort my DATATABLE

Tags: vb.net, sorting, datatable

All data shows in `dt_item` from `cache`, so how to get sorted data in `ascending order` data.

```
Dim dt_item As DataTable = CType(Cache("ITEMS"), DataTable)
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may help you
sortExp can be field on which based the sort should be performed
filterExp that should evaluate to true or false.
assuming the following fields

```
Dim filterExp As String = "Status = 'Active'"
Dim sortExp As String = "Item"
dt_item.Select(filterExp, sortExp, DataViewRowState.CurrentRows)
```

The above code shows how to filter and sort the data table dt_item. The filter expression selects Item whose status is active. The sort expression causes the results to be sorted by the Item column